# Why are Trillions formatted as Billions, when using this Custom Number Format?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I use a custom number format for numbers into the billions, which works as expected:

```
[<1000000]#,##0.0," K";  [<1000000000]#,##0.0,," M";  #,##0.0,,," B"
```

Now I need to deal with even larger numbers into the trillions, so I tried:

```
[<1000000000]#,##0.0," M"; [<1000000000000]#,##0.0,," B"; #,##0.0,,," T"
```

However, this fails - it displays one trillion (1,000,000,000,000,000) as **1,000,000.0 T**, which is actually formatted as billions, not trillions.

I've checked for solutions, eg [StackOverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773824/190925) and googled as well, but I can't see why this formatting won't work. **NOTE that the suggested SO (linked) format does NOT WORK.**

Just trying to avoid slow custom functions etc, so if anyone has a suggestion, it would be most welcome.

Comment: Check your spreadsheet locale settings - depending on the country then 1 trillion is either 10^12 (1,000,000,000,000) or 10^15 (1,000,000,000,000,000)

Comment: Thanks, but formatting has nothing to do with locale. Instead of M;B;T, they could be formatted as A;B;C or anything else.  The issue is that Google Sheets is NOT recognising the format. Try it out yourself - if you can find a way to actually make the formatting work for a trillion, I'd be very interested. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Documentation excerpt:

The [number format  documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_tokens) says this about the `,` token:

> If it appears between two digit characters (0, # or ?), then it renders the entire number with grouping separators (grouping by the thousands).

So, `=TEXT(1000, "0,0")` renders `1000` as `1,000`(It just adds a `,` every 3 digits)

> If it follows the digit characters, it scales the digits by one thousand per comma (e.g., the format #0.0,, renders the number 12,200,000 as 12.2).

So, `=TEXT(1000, "0,")`  would render `1000` as just `1`.

#### Issue:

```
[<1,000,000,000]#,##0.0," M";
[<1,000,000,000,000]#,##0.0,," B";
 #,##0.0,,," T"
```

Only a single `,` is used for `" M"`(less than 1 Billion) formatting. So, the number is only  scaled by 1000 instead of 1000^2.

#### Solution:

Add a another `,`

| Number | Fixed | Original |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Formatting: | [<1000000000]#,##0.0,," M"; [<1000000000000]#,##0.0,,," B"; #,##0.0,,,," T | [<1000000000]#,##0.0," M"; [<1000000000000]#,##0.0,," B"; #,##0.0,,," T" |
| 10 | 0.0 M | 0.0 M |
| 100 | 0.0 M | 0.1 M |
| 1000 | 0.0 M | 1.0 M |
| 10000 | 0.0 M | 10.0 M |
| 100000 | 0.1 M | 100.0 M |
| 1000000 | 1.0 M | 1,000.0 M |
| 10000000 | 10.0 M | 10,000.0 M |
| 100000000 | 100.0 M | 100,000.0 M |
| 1000000000 | 1.0 B | 1,000.0 B |
| 10000000000 | 10.0 B | 10,000.0 B |
| 100000000000 | 100.0 B | 100,000.0 B |
| 1000000000000 | 1.0 T | 1,000.0 T |
| 10000000000000 | 10.0 T | 10,000.0 T |
| 100000000000000 | 100.0 T | 100,000.0 T |
| 1000000000000000 | 1,000.0 T | 1,000,000.0 T |
| 10000000000000000 | 10,000.0 T | 10,000,000.0 T |

Answer (score 0):

This one worked correctly in Google Sheets

```
[<1000000000]#,##0.0,," M"; 
[<1000000000000]#,##0.0,,," B"; 
#,##0.0,,,," T"
```