# Need help converting text to time in duration format on Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, datetime-format, duration

Asking for some help here, im trying to convert text to time in duration format on Google Sheets, i´ve used some basic fuctions to to breakdown text (with delimiters as d (days) h (hour) m(minute) and s(second) into values that were then baked into a time function, however for outputs over 24 hours I was unable to get it to format properly i.e. in the image below 375 hrs should show 375:00:00 or [H]:mm:ss

Any ideas here?

Sharing the doc

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWHM5tPaLOulHMbfdR8CZJsER7LBceWLQrm9f8JcV9c/edit#gid=0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(, "select  "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B7:B27, 
 "d", "*86400"), "h", "*3600"), "m", "*60"), "s", "*1"), " ", "+")))/86400, 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try, in J12

```
=(G12+H12/60+I12/60/60)/24
```

then apply duration format
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror(regexextract(B7:B, "(\d+)\s*h"), 0) & ":" & 
  iferror(regexextract(B7:B, "(\d+)\s*m"), 0) & ":" & 
  iferror(regexextract(B7:B, "(\d+)\s*s"), 0) 
)
```

The formula gives text strings. To get numeric durations, use `value()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 1 / 
    value( 
      iferror(regexextract(B7:B, "(\d+)\s*h"), 0) & ":" & 
      iferror(regexextract(B7:B, "(\d+)\s*m"), 0) & ":" & 
      iferror(regexextract(B7:B, "(\d+)\s*s"), 0) 
    ) 
  ^ -1 ) 
)
```

Format the result column as **Format > Number > Duration**.

In the event there are many components in the text string you are converting, it may be beneficial to use just one `regextextract()`, which is possible using the recently introduced lambda functions:

```
=arrayformula( 
  map( 
    B7:B, 
    lambda( 
      duration, 
      if( 
        len(duration), 
        join( 
          ":", 
          iferror( 
            regexextract( 
              duration, 
              { "(\d+)\s*h"; "(\d+)\s*m"; "(\d+)\s*s" } 
            ), 
            0 
          ) 
        ), 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.