Custom Number Format in Google Sheets - hours, minutes and no zeros
I need a specific custom number format that will show me the duration in hours and minutes (with "h" & "m"), but will not show any leading zeros. You can set something like that pretty easily with Custom date and time

The problem is that this will show me fifteen minutes as "0h 15m" and I would like the number of hours to only show if there is at least one hour. The "0m" can show up if there is some whole number of hours, as this is better for clarity, but I would like the cells to be blank is the value equals 0.
I have found some setting that was advised in a different post:
[<0.0415][m]"m";[<0.083][h]"h" m"m";[h]"h" m"m"

And it does hide the hours if the time is less than an hour, but it has two downsides - it doesn't hide cells with zero values and it doesn't show the time correctly if it's negative (it shows "-300m" instead of "-5h"). I have no idea how to make those setting work. Is there someone who would know how to do it?


in the scope of your requirements, this is not doable with internal custom formatting. ofc, very easy to do with some arrayformula if you interested... see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773824/5632629


try:
=INDEX(LET(x; A2:A15; IF((x>=-0,0416608738469221)*(x<-0,000688651622112956); "-"; )&
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(x; "[h]\h m\m"); "^0h 0m$|^(?:-)?0h (?:0m)?| 0m$"; )))



@MikołajGano formula from answer updated. try now. and see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629 on how to convert english locale to non-english

Thank you for the help. I just noticed this outputs the values as text, which is not what I need, but I guess there is no way to do it then.

@MikołajGano unfortunately this is the only way. to convert back you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870176/5632629

I assume you need to use the values in calculations. You could take their format into account in future formulas. For example you could define named function CONVTIME  that takes an argument placeholder  mytimevalue. The formula would be =TIMEVALUE(JOIN(":",MAP({"h","m"},LAMBDA(t,"00"&IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(mytimevalue ,"(\d*)"&t))))))

Thank you for the functions but I need the time format to be in use in the pivot table, so this solution will not work for me. Unless someone has an idea on how to define a custom number format, I'll have to use the basic one, showing "0h 0m".

@MikołajGano the issue here is that there are not enough slots in custom number formatting to fit in all your requirements

I see. Would it be possible to make a format that will 1. hide the hours if there is less than an hour & 2. work in negative as well as the positive? Forgoing the "hide if zero" requirement I mean.

@MikołajGano https://i.sstatic.net/2fYVRFpM.png from 8 of those slots you can pick 3 only

@player0 Ok, so having the hours hide for both positive and negative is 4 options total, right? In that case there is nothing that can be done. Thanks for the explanation.
