# How can I convert a duration in minutes/seconds in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet column which has the duration column in the format as like the below.  `4w 1d 19h 56m 16s`. How can I convert this in total minutes/seconds?

PS: Every value in that list will be optional. Meaning, Sometime Weeks will be missing and days will be missing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> total minutes/seconds

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10="",,TEXT(MMULT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A10, " "), "\d+")*
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A10, " "), "\d+(.*)"), 
 {"s",1;"m",60;"h",3600;"d",86400;"w",604800}, 2, 0), 0), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1:A10, " ")), 1, 1, 0))/86400, "[mm]:ss")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the column values are simple strings and you're using Apps Script, you may be able to do something like this:

```
function transformDurationString(dString) {
  const multipliers = {
    s: 1,
    m: 60,
    h: 60 * 60,
    d: 60 * 60 * 24,
    w: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  };

  let totalSeconds = 0;
  let durations = dString.split(" ");
  
  for (const duration of durations) {
    const durationValue = Number(duration.slice(0, -1));
    const durationType = duration.slice(-1);

    totalSeconds += durationValue * multipliers[durationType];
  }

  const totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  const remainderSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;

  return `${totalMinutes}m ${totalSeconds}s`;
}
```