# Excel custom number format

Tags: excel, format, numbers

Excel custom number format:

I would like to use this custom number format for negative values as well.

[>=1000000]$#.##0.."M";[>=1000]$#.##0."K";$#.##0

M: for million
K: for thousands

I've tried to add conditions to the format but I keep getting errors.

Comment: [This could be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773823/ultimate-short-custom-number-formatting-k-m-b-t-etc-q-d-googol)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ultimate short custom number formatting - K, M, B, T, etc., Q, D, Googol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773823/ultimate-short-custom-number-formatting-k-m-b-t-etc-q-d-googol)